# Is a Bugbear's Long Limbed reach also applied to shoves and grapples?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, grapple, reach, bugbear

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111115/can-battle-master-maneuvers-also-apply-to-special-attacks), I have been told the difference between a "melee attack" (which, if I understand correctly, Shoves and Grapples are) and a "melee **weapon** attack" (which they are not).

A Bugbear's Long Limbed feature gives him 5 feet of extra reach for melee attacks made on his turn.

So, is a Bugbear's Long Limbed reach also applied to special attacks (Shoves & Grapples)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Yes - As long as it is on your turn

Long-limbed

> When you make a **melee attack** **on your turn**, your reach for it is 5 feet
>   greater than normal.

Grapple

> ...you can use the Attack action to make a **special melee attack**, a grapple....
>
> The target of your grapple must be no more than one size larger than you and must be **within your reach**.

Shove

> Using the Attack action, you can make a **special melee attack** to shove...
>
> The target must be no more than one size larger than you and must be **within your reach**.

As long as you Grapple or Shove *on your turn* then you can apply the extra reach from long-limbed.

Comment: It is worth noting that long limbed only applies on your turn, so the grapple could not be *maintained*

Comment: @Exempt-Medic: worse, it only applies *for the attack* (if it applied for the bugbear's whole turn, it could close to 5ft after grappling if it had the movement, but that's not possible since the grapple breaks first).