# If I trip with a weapon do I add the Weapon Focus bonus to the trip attack roll?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, combat-maneuver, trip

Some special attacks such as [Trip](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#trip) can be performed with weapons. Its text says:

> Some weapons can be used to make trip attacks. In this case, **you make a melee touch attack with the weapon** instead of an unarmed melee touch attack, and you don’t provoke an attack of opportunity.

Supposing I am using a [Flail](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#flailorHeavyFlail) (or other weapon which allows tripping with it) and I have [Weapon Focus](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#weaponFocus) with the Flail, do I add the Weapon Focus bonus to the Trip check (i.e., the melee touch attack with the flail)?

P.s.: similar to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93280/how-do-attack-bonuses-affect-special-attacks-with-combat-maneuvers), but I want an answer for D&D 3.5 instead of Pathfinder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes.

[Weapon Focus](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#weaponFocus) provides the following benefit (**emphasis** mine):

> You gain a +1 bonus on **all attack rolls you make using the selected weapon**.

As quoted in your question, when you use a weapon to trip, you make your trip attack with that weapon (**emphasis** again mine):

> Some weapons can be used to make trip attacks. In this case, you make a **melee touch attack with the weapon** instead of an unarmed melee touch attack, and you don’t provoke an attack of opportunity.

Touch attacks are attacks, and they use attack rolls.  From [the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm):

> Some attacks disregard armor, including shields and natural armor. In these cases, the attacker makes a touch attack roll (either ranged or melee).

So, to sum up;

- When you trip with a weapon, you make a touch attack with the weapon.
- When you make a touch attack, it includes an attack roll.
- Weapon Focus provides a bonus on all attack rolls you make with the selected weapon.

Therefore, Weapon Focus provides its bonus on trip attacks made with the selected weapon.